# How to fully manage the android phone from a PC

Tags: windows-10, android

Most of the time when I am in the office, my phone stays connected to the computer. I have my headset on all the time as well. Sometimes when I get a phone call, it is really disturbing to get headset off and answer the call on the phone. I was hoping  to find an app that can communicate with my phone, so that I can make phone calls and answer the calls without touching the phone. But I didn't find an app that does it. Maybe I didn't look hard enough. I was wondering if someone came cross with this problem and found a solution? This saves lots of time and makes the productivity high.
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have Samsung S9+ (in case if there is a Samsung specific app).

Answer (score 2):

Glad you asked... Assuming you are using a recent version of Windows 10, you can use the "Your Phone" app from windows store(comes pre-installed with windows 10 v1809 onwards) to fully manage your phone..send messages make calls even mirror the phone screen.

Read more here: https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-your-phone-app-can-now-be-used-to-make-calls-from-android-phones/

You will have to install the "[Your Phone Companion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.appmanager&hl=en)" app on your android phone

Comment: I have Windows 10 1903 installed and I also tried the Your Phone app, but I can't get the app to make phone calls. It only allows me to manage SMS and Notifications. Is there an additional setting that I should turn on?

Comment: @Dilshod In the Your Phone app, open settings page and check if it  will allow you to toggle on the ability to "allow this app to make and manage calls from my phone".  ?